# How can I adjust my code to make sure that my iterator code accepts user input?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand why my iterator code will not print the correct statement even though I am passing the correct variable through to it. I am still new to C++ and have figured that this is probably an easy fix but could anyone help ??

Ps - it works fine when I have already declared an input but when I wish for the code to accept user input it gives inaccurate results

```
int main(){

list<string> personWords = {"Baxter","Nao","Jane"};
list <string> actionWords ={"recognise","detect","sees","pick","eats","lifts"};
list <string> directionWords = {"left","right","forwards","backwards"};
list <string> pronounWords = {"I","you","him","her"};
list <string> objectWords = {"apple","car","bus","diamond","atom","ball"};
list <string> textureWords = {"smooth","rough","shiny"};


string userInput;
cin >> userInput;
string userInputWords[3];
int counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i <= userInput.length(); i++){
    if (userInput[i] == ' '){

        counter++;}
    else{
        userInputWords[counter] += userInput[i];
    }
}
// The above for loop counts the number of words using the
// number of spaces inbetween the words and stores them in an 
// array

cout << userInputWords[0] << endl; // A check to see that correct word is being printed



list <string> ::iterator check1;
check1 = find(personWords.begin(),  personWords.end(), userInputWords[0]);

// searching for all of the person words


if(check1 != personWords.end()){ 
    cout << "Your word exists in Person Words list" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "Your word does not exist in Person Words list" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: [Off Topic] `std::list` is almost/always never the container you should be using.  It has terrible memory locality and destroys caches (the thing that makes cpu's really fast).  `std::vector` should be you go to container if you need a sequence container. (and may other types as well but we'll ignore that for now)

Comment: Print the input immediately after reading — it’s not what you think. Then read about how formatted input with `>>` works in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: It’s s good idea to be more specific than ”gives inaccurate results”. What are the results and what were you expecting?

Comment: The results I get when I get allow for a user to type in a sentence; although the first word they type is within the list, my code does not recognise that it is and so returns the statement that it is not in the list. The results I want is simply for my code to recognise when a user types in a sentence and it is returns the statement that it is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is probably an easy fix

```
for(int i = 0; i <= userInput.length(); i++)
                 ^^
```

It should just be

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
```

When it is *less than or equals*, it adds all the characters the user typed **plus one**.

That's why `std::find` couldn't find what you were typing, because it was also grabbing whatever was right after the word (probably a `\0`, but don't quote me on that.)

Comment: Yeah this solution has fixed my problem. Thank you very much !